# Resolvent of the operator

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider the Laplace operator defined on the biggest possible subset of$L^{2}(R^{2})$:

$T= - \partial^{2}_{x} -\partial^{2}_{y}+x^{2}+y^{2}+ 2.i(x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$

Let $\alpha \not\in\sigma(T)$ and let $(T-\alpha I)^{-1}u(x,y)=f(x,y)$.

Now,  let $F$ be the Fourier transform $(\zeta,\eta)$. We have

$\Big[(\zeta^{2} +\eta^{2})-\partial^{2}_{\zeta} -\partial^{2}_{\eta}-2i(\eta \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}-\zeta\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}) -\alpha I)\Big]\widehat{f}(\zeta,\eta)=\widehat{u}(\zeta,\eta)$

So, I need to calculate  the resolvent of this operator. Does anybody have any ideas how to complete this.

Comment: How does $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ become $-\partial_\zeta^2-\partial_\eta^2$? Is there a typo here?

Comment: I'm sorry there is not the root in $(x^{2}+y^{2})$.

Comment: Calculate the eigenfunctions : T is the Hamiltonian of an electron in a constant magnetic field perpendicular to the plane. The eigenfunctions are the elements of the Landau levels.

Comment: I try to calculate the resolvent, what is the relationship with the eigenvalues. thnks

Comment: So what is the point of the Fourier transform? You are just getting the same operator back.